# Spring, Mustache Starter - translations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mustache

I try to configure my project to support internationalization.

I wrote simple configuration based on configuration for JSP that I used recently.

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.mustache.java.LocalizationMessageInterceptor;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;


    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = new String[]{
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }

    /* Internationalization beans */

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");

        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale(environment.getProperty("system.default.language")));

        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ret.setBasename("classpath:translations");
        ret.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        ret.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public LocalizationMessageInterceptor getLocalizationMessageInterceptor(MessageSource messageSource, LocaleResolver localeResolver) {
        LocalizationMessageInterceptor lmi = new LocalizationMessageInterceptor();
        lmi.setLocaleResolver(localeResolver);
        lmi.setMessageSource(messageSource);
        return lmi;
    }

}
```

In html files I cannot access translation values.

```
${app.name}
```

is not resolved,

```
{{app.name}}
```

causes an exception

```
No method or field with name 'app'
```

Translation files are placed under resources catalogue, default language is set:

```
system.default.language=en
```

**EDIT:**
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Gateway Application</name>
    <description>Gateway Application Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <spring-webmvc-pac4j.version>1.1.1</spring-webmvc-pac4j.version>
        <pac4j.version>1.9.1</pac4j.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <apache-commons.version>3.4</apache-commons.version>
        <spring-devtools.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring-devtools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sps.mustache</groupId>
            <artifactId>mustache-spring-view</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PAC4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-http</artifactId>
            <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-pac4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-webmvc-pac4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE**

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or plain Spring?

Comment: Spring Boot with spring-boot-starter-mustache, I will add pom.xml dependencies to post.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you don't need to configure the messagesource, that is already done for you (and you can simply add properties to the `application.properties` to configure it`). Also post your full configuration class and pom.

Comment: I added full configuration class and pom file.

Comment: For starters you don't need the `MessageSource` nor resource configuration (Spring Boot already does that for you). Next to that the `LocalizationMessageInterceptor` is a `HandlerInterceptor` but you nowhere register it (that bean could as well not be there), it should also be added to the `InterceptorRegistry` like the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`.

Comment: Also according to [the documentation](https://github.com/sps/mustache-spring-view/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/MustacheLocalizationMessageInterceptor.java) (when the interceptor has been registered correctly). You should do something like `{{#i18n}}your.key{{/i18n}}` in your template.

Comment: @M.Deinum - now everything works fine, I will post whole solution. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some unnecessary configuration. Short summarisation in 4 points.

1. **AppConfig.java**

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Inject
       private Environment environment;

       @Inject
       private MessageSource messageSource;

       /* Internationalization beans */

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
           registry.addInterceptor(getLocalizationMessageInterceptor());
       }

       @Bean
       public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
           LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
           localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");

           return localeChangeInterceptor;
       }


       @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
       public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
           CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
           localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale(environment.getProperty("system.default.language")));

           return localeResolver;
       }

       @Bean
       public LocalizationMessageInterceptor getLocalizationMessageInterceptor() {
           LocalizationMessageInterceptor lmi = new LocalizationMessageInterceptor();
           lmi.setLocaleResolver(getLocaleResolver());
           lmi.setMessageSource(messageSource);
           return lmi;

       }
   }
   ```

As @M. Deinum said MessageSource and resource configuration is done by starters so we don't need it.

2. **pom.xml**

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.sps.mustache</groupId>
           <artifactId>mustache-spring-view</artifactId>
           <version>1.3</version>
       </dependency>
   ```

   mustache-spring-view is needed because of org.springframework.web.servlet.view.mustache.jmustache.LocalizationMessageInterceptor.
3. **message.properties**
   For default locale (en) file message.properties is required.
   For different locale file message_LOCALE.properties is used.

Those files should be placed under resources/.

4. **HTML files**
   Message values can be accessed in HTML file with notation

   ```
      {{#i18n}}message-key{{/i18n}}
   ```